# Anchor tag '<a>' not working on first click inside Slick

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I am placing an anchor tag inside slick slider (React-Slick), it is not working on the first click, but on the second click onwards , this is for each image.
Code :

```
<MediaQuery query={`(max-device-width: ${belowIpadBreakPoint}px)`}>
                <Slider className="marketing-carousel__body" {...settings}>
                    {objectPath.has(this.state, 'config.content.images') &&
                        this.state.config.content.images.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index.toString()} className="marketing-carousel__body_image">
                                     { this.state.config.content.ctaLink ?
                                        <a href={this.state.config.content.ctaLink} target={this.state.config.content.ctaTarget} id="marketing-carousel-mobile-link">
                                            <Picture
                                                sources={item.sources}
                                                defaultSrc={item.defaultSrc}
                                                isLazyLoad={item.isLazyLoad}
                                                altText={item.altText}
                                                customClass={item.customClass}
                                            />
                                        </a>
                                        :
                                        <Picture
                                                sources={item.sources}
                                                defaultSrc={item.defaultSrc}
                                                isLazyLoad={item.isLazyLoad}
                                                altText={item.altText}
                                                customClass={item.customClass}
                                        />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                </Slider>
```

Comment: can u put this code on codesandbox would be much easier to debug

Comment: This code has many dependencies, it is basically an image carousel, but I have placed an anchor tag around it, this is changing the class of anchor tag to "link-active" from the first click itself, but is not working for the first click. I will try to replicate with a slider and some images in sandbox anyways :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-kdkrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed it on my own.
This is what I did:

```
  <a href={this.state.config.content.ctaLink} target={this.state.config.content.ctaTarget} onClick={(e) => this.openLinks(e)}>
```

I put an onClick listener and created a function. This seemed to have solved the issue, it is an existing issue with slick.js.

```
  openLinks = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.currentTarget.target === '_blank') {
        window.open(event.currentTarget.href, event.currentTarget.target);
    } else {
        window.location = event.currentTarget.href;
    }
};
```